# Angular UI Bootstrap Modal pass data back to parent controller on background click / ESC keyboard close

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

everyone.

Will start from the prob - How can i pass the variable back from the AngularJS UI Boostrap Modal on the user's background click or ESC button keyboard trigger?

there are solution to prevent user for doing that:
[How do I prevent angular-ui modal from closing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20286445/how-do-i-prevent-angular-ui-modal-from-closing)

But in my case, i think it can make a user stuck, because there is only one btn triggering the `$uibModalInstance.close($scope.choosenLocationLatLng);` action. 
So i want to pass the variable back on background click and ESC keyboard btn also if its possible.

Answer (score 0):

The closing event of $uibModal can be trapped and used to communicate with parent controller.

```
//main controller
var modalInstance = $uibModal.open({
  templateUrl: 'a-template.html',
  controller: ['$scope','$rootScope', function($scope, $){
    //This goes in modal ctrl
    //----------------------------------------------------------
    $scope.$on('modal.hide', function(event, reason, closed){
           $scope.$on("modal.closing",function(){
           $rootScope.$broadcast("modalClosing",$scope.latLong);
     });
    }
    //---------------------------------------------------------
  }],
  controllerAs: 'modal',
  size: 'lg'
});
$scope.$on('modalClosing',function(value){
  //value is the latlong set in modal
})
```

Comment: sorry, i dont really understood. so, i need to pass a whole $scope inmodal controller and here `$scope.$on('modal.hide', function(event, reason, closed){
       //use the data from the factory/service(set in the modal) here.
    }`

capture the needed value?

Comment: Did you tested smth like that?
done that, but no errors, just nothing happened. `$scope.$on('modal.hide'` in modal's controller is not fired

Comment: I have created a plnkr. Sorry the event name was wrong up there. Corrected the code also
http://plnkr.co/edit/zHnFmR2SPJ4BFvGU0XL4

Comment: just tried to put this in modal's controller 
`$scope.$on('modal.hide', function(event, reason, closed){
        console.log("modal hide fired");
        $scope.$on("modal.closing",function(){
            console.log("modal closing fired");
            $rootScope.$broadcast("modalClosing",$scope.choosenLocationLatLng);
        });
    });`

nothing logging on background click modal closing or ESC keyboard closing.

Comment: can you create a plnkr? or check the plnkr I gave .. its working fine and logging the value